# ASP.Net Core - setting and getting session variables

Tags: asp.net-core

I have an application using ASP.NET Core, Angular 5 And ADO.NET

It worked fine until I decided to change the code to set a session variable with a database connection string gotten from my appssettings.json file.

I am using this as a reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2

However, when I try to set the session variable, I get a Null object reference in my SetSessionVariable() method.

Error is:

> An error occurred while starting the application.
>   NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object. Angular5NetcoreAdo.Startup.SetSessionVariable() in Startup.cs,
>   line 82

My code is:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Angular5NetcoreAdo.Models;

// Added these.
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System;

namespace Angular5NetcoreAdo
{
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // Added this.
    public HttpContext HttpContext { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory.
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });

        services.AddScoped<EmployeeDataAccessLayer>();

        // Added this.
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = ".ConnectionString";
        });

        // Added this.
        SetSessionVariable();
    }

    // Added this.
    public void SetSessionVariable()
    {
         HttpContext.Session.SetString("ConnectionString", Convert.ToString(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBAngular5NetcoreAdoDatabase")));
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

        // Added this.
        app.UseSession();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---- Per a suggestion below, I am including that code here:

```
// Middleware extension method.

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;

namespace Angular5NetcoreAdo
{
    public static class RequestConnectionMiddlewareExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseRequestConnection(this 
IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<RequestConnectionMiddleware>();
        }
    }
}

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace Angular5NetcoreAdo
{
    public class RequestConnectionMiddleware
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public HttpContext HttpContext { get; }

        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public RequestConnectionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, 
IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _next = next;

            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            // Set the session variable with the database connection string from appsettings.json.
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("ConnectionString", Convert.ToString(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBAngular5NetcoreAdoDatabase")));

            await _next(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Now in the Startup.cs, I call the new middleware message method after the app.UseSession();

```
app.UseSession();

// Call the middlware now to set the session variable with the database
// connection string from appsettings.json. 
app.UseRequestConnection();
```

------------------ Added now as a new error refers to this class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace Angular5NetcoreAdo.Models
{
    public class EmployeeDataAccessLayer
    {
       public HttpContext HttpContext { get; }
       public string connectionString;

       public EmployeeDataAccessLayer(HttpContext httpContext)
       {
           // Set the property.
           HttpContext = httpContext;

           // Get the connection string session variable.
           connectionString = HttpContext.Session.GetString("ConnectionString");
       }

       public IEnumerable<Employee> GetAllEmployees()
       {
          try
           {
               List<Employee> lstemployee = new List<Employee>();

               using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
               {
                   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SelectEmployees", con);
                   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                   con.Open();

                   SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                   while (rdr.Read())
                   {
                       Employee employee = new Employee();

                       employee.ID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["EmployeeID"]);
                       employee.Name = rdr["Name"].ToString();
                       employee.Gender = rdr["Gender"].ToString();
                       employee.Department = rdr["Department"].ToString();
                       employee.City = rdr["City"].ToString();

                       lstemployee.Add(employee);
                   }

                   rdr.Close();
                   con.Close();
               }

               return lstemployee;
           }
           catch
           {
               throw;
           }
       }

       public Employee GetEmployeeData(int id)
       {
           try
           {
               Employee employee = new Employee();

               using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
               {
                   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SelectEmployeeById", con);
                   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpId", id);

                   con.Open();

                   SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                   while (rdr.Read())
                   {
                       employee.ID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["EmployeeID"]);
                       employee.Name = rdr["Name"].ToString();
                       employee.Gender = rdr["Gender"].ToString();
                       employee.Department = rdr["Department"].ToString();
                       employee.City = rdr["City"].ToString();
                   }

                   rdr.Close();
                   con.Close();
               }

               return employee;
           }
           catch
           {
               throw;
           }
       }

       public int AddEmployee(Employee employee)
       {
           try
           {
               using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
               {
                   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertEmployee", con);
                   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", employee.Name);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", employee.City);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", employee.Department);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", employee.Gender);

                   con.Open();

                   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                   con.Close();
               }

               return 1;
           }
           catch
           {
               throw;
           }
       }

       public int UpdateEmployee(Employee employee)
       {
           try
           {
               using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
               {
                   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdateEmployee", con);
                   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpId", employee.ID);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", employee.Name);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", employee.City);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", employee.Department);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", employee.Gender);

                   con.Open();

                   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    con.Close();
               }

               return 1;
           }
           catch
           {
               throw;
           }
       }

       public int DeleteEmployee(int id)
       {
           try
           {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
               {
                   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DeleteEmployee", con);
                   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpId", id);

                   con.Open();

                   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    con.Close();
              }

               return 1;
          }
        catch
           {
               throw;
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its because documentation says

> HttpContext.Session can't be accessed before UseSession has been
>   called.

and you call it in ConfigurationServices method where HttpContext.Session does not exist yet.

So you will need [create your own middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and call it after `UseSession()` method in Configure method.

Comment: As per that 'create your middleware' link you included above, I created the middleware, placed the call to it after the UseSession() and I still get the same error. I included this code above for review.

Comment: @user3020047 You tried change HttpContext.Session. to context.Session ?

Comment: @user3020047 That's because you're executing `HttpContext.Session.SetString...` in your `RequestConnectionMiddleware.Invoke(context)`, the `HttpContext` here is not passed from the parameter `context` , but from the `Property` of this middleware. Since you have never set this `Property`, it is `null` all the time

Comment: @itminus I added a set; to the property HttpContext. Then in the InvokeAsync() method I added: HttpContext = context; I now get an error on the next line __> await _next(context); ---->InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext' while attempting to activate 'Angular5NetcoreAdo.Models.EmployeeDataAccessLayer'.

Comment: @daremachine I changed it to context.Sesson and I get the error: I now get an error on the next line __> await _next(context); ---->InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext' while attempting to activate 'Angular5NetcoreAdo.Models.EmployeeDataAccessLayer'. ---> The same error as the suggestion from above. Note: I added the EmployeeDataAccessLayer code above for review but I don't get why this error message would have issue with it.

Comment: @user3020047  That's because you're trying to inject a  `HttpContext` to an `EmployeeDataAccessLayer` . You need inject `IHttpContextAccessor` instead . Don't forget to use `services.AddHttpContextAccessor()` to register that service.